# MVC4 MiniProfiler results-index page errors "MiniProfiler.list is undefined"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-mini-profiler, mvcminiprofiler

I get the error "MiniProfiler.list is undefined" error when trying to load the miniprofiler list:
 `/mini-profiler-resources/results-index`

The javascript miniprofiler injects doesn't have any method or property called "list".

The page that shows one results trace works fine.

I'm using Nuget to install the packages, removed the current version of MiniProfiler and install latest:

```
Install-Package MiniProfiler
```

Then:

```
Install-Package MiniProfiler.Mvc4
```

Can't find anyone else having same problem so it must be me! Am I missing something obvious here? I also added the handlers in my web.config although I have `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` but still nothing.

Comment: We're seeing it too... :(

Answer (score 10):

It seems that results-index page is currently broken from version 3.0.10 through now (3.1.1.140).

It still works in the older version installed via `Install-Package MiniProfiler -Version 2.1`, so that's still an option if there is a more urgent need for the results index than any features available in 3.x.

Looking through the source code for MiniProfiler, it seems that the UI was broken out for version 3.x into a separate git project and support for list mode is missing. The JS Miniprofiler object lives in a source file in the UI project named includes.js, and according to the source code for the initial commit in git, there's no symbol for list.

[Miniprofiler/ui/includes.js,initial, Lines 633-953 @ github](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/ui/blob/0ccd6e79dda18c08c24a80fc4d8771f67056d4a0/includes.js#L633-L953)

The source code that emits the results-index page in Miniprofiler/dotnet hasn't been updated since 2013, so perhaps the results-index page is deprecated or just not updated yet.

[Miniprofiler/dotnet/StackExchange.Profiling/MiniProfilerHandler.cs,latest, Lines 186-205 @ github](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/MiniProfilerHandler.cs#L186-L205)

There's also an open issue for 3.x listed in github here:

[Can not view results-index - Miniprofiler.list is undefined @ github](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/80)

Comment: latest release of v3.2.0 resolves this issue. https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/releases/tag/v3.2.0